# How to read parameter from the HTTP query string

Tags: drupal, query-string

I have the following URL

```
http://www.example.com/node/add/forum/3?gids[]=13
```

I want to get the value `13` from within my module.

I've tried with

```
$_GET['gid[]']
```

and with

```
$_GET['gids%5B%5D']
```

but I always get `null`.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried print_r($_GET['gids']); ? or echo $_GET['gids'][1]; ?

Comment: … or, more generally, print_r($_REQUEST) since the OP is unsure about how that query parameter will be named. In this case, Joe has the answer below: They are automatically put into an array named 'gids'.

Comment: @Chumillas: I haven't. but [Joe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126795/how-to-read-parameter-from-the-http-query-string/6126877#6126877) put me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the URL is correctly encoded (gids%5B%5D) and that's the only element in the array, then the contents of that first element in gids would be in `$_GET['gids'][0]`.

Comment: thanks: that was it!!! One more question: you write "Drupal has its own way of handling the query string", and do you know where I can read about it? I've searched but did not find documentation on this topic. Any link to useful documentation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about `arg()`, which only deals with the path query string variable (`$_GET['q']`). Updated to remove the bit about dealing with all `$_GET` variables.

Comment: If you use this, you must clean the input or you have just opened up a XSS security hole in your site.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is tagged with the keyword "drupal" and comes up on Google searches. The Drupal 7 way of doing it and makes it easy is to use [drupal_get_query_parameters()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7). This will return an associate array of all variables and values from the query string all at once.

By using this, when you store the information coming from the URL it has been sanitized for XSS and SQLi attacks.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer since this is the Drupal way.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.2+, use [`filter_input()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to read GET and POST variables:

```
$gids = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'gids', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY | FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: thanks! this may be useful in the future. For my current purposes, [Joe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126795/how-to-read-parameter-from-the-http-query-string/6126877#6126877) did the job.